# Не работают стили css в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Пытаюсь вызывать меню по клику на элемент div

Хочу чтобы по клику на элемент с `id="open_menu_id"`
CSS стиль `display` у элемента `menu_box` менялся на `block`
Вот этот код:

```js
$(document.ready(function() {
  $('#menu_box').css('display', 'none');
  $('#open_menu_id').click(function() {
    $('#menu_box').css('display', 'block');
  });
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-bar">
  <li class="menu">
    <div class="person">
      <img class="user_img" src="../images/user.png" alt="user" />
      <div id="open_menu_id" class="open_menu">admin</div>
    </div>
    <ul id="menu_box" class="menu_2">
      <a href="">
        <li class="menu_item">Профиль</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li class="menu_item">Настройки</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li class="menu_item">Выход</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Но ничего не работает.  Я только начинаю разбираться с jQuery, подскажите, что делаю не правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Вы просто перепутали и написали:

```
$(document.ready(function () {
}));
```

А надо:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

---

*P.S. Так же можно использовать метод `.show(), .hide()`, чтобы отобразить блок, вместо присвоения стилей вручную.*

> [**`.show()`**](http://api.jquery.com/show/): This is roughly equivalent to calling `.css( "display", "block" )`
>
> [**`.hide()`**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/): This is roughly equivalent to calling `.css( "display", "none" )`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu_box').hide()
  $('#open_menu_id').click(function() {
    $('#menu_box').show()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu-bar">
  <li class="menu">
    <div class="person">
      <img class="user_img" src="../images/user.png" alt="user" />
      <div id="open_menu_id" class="open_menu">admin</div>
    </div>
    <ul id="menu_box" class="menu_2">
      <a href="">
        <li class="menu_item">Профиль</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li class="menu_item">Настройки</li>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <li class="menu_item">Выход</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```